# How to draw a plot with a zoomed in portion next to it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

[image]

How to add zoom area and to give and label top x axis?

Here is my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
   scaled ticks=false,
   xmin=0,
   ymin=0,
   xlabel=In,
   ylabel=out,
 ]
    \addplot[domain=15:140, blue, ultra thick,smooth] {10000/(9999*e^(-0.125*x)+10)+120};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
   scaled ticks=false,
   xmin=20,
   ymin=80,
   xlabel=In,
   ylabel=out,

 ]
    \addplot[domain=5:40, blue, ultra thick,smooth] {10000/(9999*e^(-0.125*x)+10)+100};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 15):

Here's a suggestion. There are some comments in the code, ask if anything is unclear.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

% if this is uncommented, all the instances of "axis cs:" below can be removed
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

% calc library required for the ($(..)+(..)$) coordinate syntax
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  % as the function is used more than once, make a shorthand
  declare function={
   f(\x)=10000/(9999*e^(-0.125*\x)+10)+100;
  }
]
 \begin{axis}[
   scaled ticks=false,
   xmin=0,
   ymin=0,
   xlabel=In,
   ylabel=out,
   % add a name to the axis, used to position the second one
   name=ax1
 ]

 \addplot[domain=15:140, blue, ultra thick,smooth] {f(x)};

  % define coordinates at bottom left and top left of rectangle
  \coordinate (c1) at (axis cs:20,80);
  \coordinate (c2) at (axis cs:20,240);
  % draw a rectangle
  \draw (c1) rectangle (axis cs:42,240);


\end{axis}

 \begin{axis}[
   name=ax2,
   scaled ticks=false,
   xmin=20,xmax=42,
   ymin=80,ymax=240,
   xlabel=In,
   ylabel=out,
   % place second axis relative to first one
   % anchor is south west
   at={($(ax1.south east)+(2cm,0)$)},
   % turn on grid
   xmajorgrids=true,
   grid style={help lines,dashed},
   % to avoid clipping of a...e nodes
   clip=false
 ]
    \addplot[domain=20:40, blue, ultra thick,smooth] {f(x)};


    \foreach \x/\txt in {20/a,25/b,30/c,35/d,40/e}
    {
     \edef\temp{\noexpand\draw [dashed] (axis cs:\x,{f(\x)}) coordinate (tmp) -- ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-tmp) node[left] {\txt};}
      \temp
    }

\end{axis}

% third axis for the top axis
\begin{axis}[
at={(ax2.south west)},
% put x-axis labels etc. on top
axis x line=top,
% remove arrow tip
axis line style={-},
axis y line=none,
xmin=20,xmax=42,
ymin=0,ymax=5,
xlabel=stuff,
xticklabels={,10,9,8,7,6}
]

\end{axis}

% draw dashed lines from rectangle in first axis to corners of second
\draw [dashed] (c1) -- (ax2.south west);
\draw [dashed] (c2) -- (ax2.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (Too late in the evening for more thorough explanations.)

Comment: ! Package pgfkeys Error: Choice '1.11' unknown in key '/pgfplots/compat/anchors
'. I am going to ignore this key.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.47 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
  ?          this error I got

Comment: @redPil Then you have a rather old version of `pgfplots`, the current version is 1.15, you must have one older than 1.11. I'll edit in an hour or two, basically you'll need to use `(axis cs:x,y)` instead of `(x,y)` for `\draw` etc inside an `axis` env, and remove that `compat` setting.

Comment: @redPil I've updated the code in my answer as described.

Comment: ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/clip mode' and I am going
 to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.64 \end{axis}
?  this error I got. I can run left figure  and add top x axis, but I guess problem with right figure.

Comment: @redPil Sure you don't want to just upgrade your LaTeX distribution? Anyways, change from `clip mode=individual` to `clip=false`, and change from `domain=5:40` to `domain=20:40`.

Comment: Also, how to label top x axis (stuff) starts from 10 to 6 instead of from 0 to 4.

Comment: @redPil Updated answer again.

Comment: ! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input 'f(20)' as a floating point num
ber, sorry. The unreadable part was near 'f(20)'..

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.64 \end{axis}. This is other error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66348/discussion-between-torbjorn-t-and-redpil).